# How to change format of time

Tags: php

I have a $_POST ($_POST['durationChosen']) which is a time and its format is '00 Hrs 00 Mins 00 Secs'. Now I still want to display this format in the textbox but on the next page I want $_POST['durationChosen'] I want the format to be '00:00:00'. How can I do this?

An example is in the textbox I have '01 Hrs 30 Mins 15 Secs' but in next page I want it formatted so its '01:30:15'. Can this be done?

Comment: That will show `01:30:15:`. I think you mean: `str_replace(array(' Hrs ', ' Mins ', ' Secs'), array(':', ':', ''), $_POST['durationChosen'])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

  $array = sscanf($_POST['durationChosen'], "%u %s %u %s %u %s");

  $time = date('H:i:s', strtotime($array[0] . ':' . $array[2] . ':' . $array[4]));
```

**Edit to reflect comment of acceptance below:**

```
<?php

      $time = str_replace(array(' Hrs ', ' Mins ', ' Secs'), array(':', ':', ''), $_POST['durationChosen']);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, it is actually the one you mentioned in the comment which I used: $time = str_replace(array(' Hrs ', ' Mins ', ' Secs'), array(':', ':', ''), $_POST['durationChosen']); and then I can use $time to insert into database. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). The problem with your coding is that, you are using short notation of time, which the data function does not understand. [Read here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php)

A simple way to get around this

```
$time = $_POST['durationChosen'];
$time= str_replace("Hrs", "Hour", $time);
$time= str_replace("Mins", "minutes", $time);
$time= str_replace("Secs", "seconds", $time);

$time = strtotime($time);
echo date($time, "H:i:s");
```

Comment: its pointless to use date and strtotime when you can solve it with str_replace alone.

Comment: @Gordon, The concept was to get him use correct date formats.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with explode function

```
$tm = explode(' ', $_POST['durationChosen']);

$dt = date('H:i:s', strtotime($tm[0].':'.$tm[2].':'.$tm[4]));
```